# Woocommerce product purchase to be displayed monthly wise in orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'e set up a woocommerce hotel booking website for a club & that should be able to show the purchases made by any member based on month wise. Currently the orders section will display all the purchases one below the other but my client is expecting the purchases made by any logged in member to be displayed on monthly basis. Is there any tweaks or tricks that can be done within the woocommerce core files that would help me display the orders based on each individual month?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this, [Woocommerce Order Reports](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/reports/)

You can view the orders by each month, Orders by category , Orders by product as well. Sort the orders here with this woocommerce default functionality.

Comment: Sorry for not being relevant in my question. Will this be available in the user login front end? The user who should see is a subscriber/customer of the hotel. He/she should be able to see what purchase he has done on a monthly basis?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this Free Plugin , [WooCommerce Sales MIS Report](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-mis-report/)

You can shows you all key sales information in one main Dashboard in very easy to understand format which gives a quick overview of your business and helps you make better decisions,
Plugin shows summaries like –

- Total Order
- Recent Orders
- Order Status
- Order Summary
- Top n Products
- Customers, Country
- Today, Yesterday
- This Week
- This Month
- This Year
- Date Filters
- Export to Excel

Comment: Sorry for not being relevant in my question. Will this be available in the user login front end? The user who should see is a subscriber/customer of the hotel. He/she should be able to see what purchase he has done on a monthly basis?

Comment: Woocommerce give default functionality to user can show order in myaccount
so please in front end after login ,Myaccount>Orders

Comment: Ya @Arpan Sagar, but can I divide that orders section to display my purchases on monthly basis?

Comment: Yes its possible.But its need to customize woocommere plugin.
No any plugin give default functionality for display purchases on monthly basis.

Comment: any link that would be a great tweak to core woocommerce files that would help me achieve this will be really great. Thanks.